# Formatting decimal leading with zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, format, decimal

I have a requirement which says, it should be rounded by two decimal places and should contain 8 digits as result.

```
   Output Example:
   1234567.88  to 12345678  -- As format is only for 8 digit by removing decimal
   123.45      to 00012345
   748.55137   to 00074855
```

For this I have done below way, in which FORMAT or LEFT is not working.

```
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT('00000000'+LEFT(CAST(CAST( ROUND((((ISNULL(511.90,0)*(ISNULL(146.230,0)/100))),2) AS DECIMAL( 15,0)) AS VARCHAR( 15 )), 8 ), 8 ),'.','')
 Expected Output: 00074855
```

I have done `LEFT`, `FORMAT(.., '00000.00')` but nothing seems working here in CASE.

Thanks all for the inputs.

```
Working Sample: 

REPLACE(FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(((ISNULL(511.90,0) * (ISNULL(146.230,0)/100))),2) AS DECIMAL(10,2)),'000000.00'),'.','')
```

Comment: Is always the input with 2 decimal values?

Comment: What are the expected results for 129.70 and 12345678.99 ?

Comment: For values in the question, simple `SELECT LEFT(FORMAT(Amount * 100, '00000000'), 8)` returns the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Statement `SELECT LEFT(FORMAT(Amount * 100, '00000000'), 8)`, using [LEFT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [FORMAT() with custom formatting string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-format-with-custom-formatting-strings), returns the expected results:

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   Amount, 
   LEFT(FORMAT(Amount * 100, '00000000'), 8) AS FormattedAmount
FROM (
   VALUES (1234567.88), (123.45), (748.55137)
) v (Amount)
```

Result:

```
Amount          FormattedAmount
1234567.88000   12345678
123.45000       00012345
748.55137       00074855
```

Comment: Thanks for answer this is working I have made modification, REPLACE(FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(((ISNULL(SchBenf.MBS_FEEAMT,0) * (ISNULL(SchBenf.GAP_Percentage,0)/100))),2) AS DECIMAL(10,2)),'000000.00'),'.','')

Comment: @ShwetaReddy Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using [REPLICATE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
 function.

Here `8` is the length you want of the text including padding `0`.

```
declare @id as varchar(10) = replace('1234567.88', '.', '')
SELECT Convert(Varchar(8),CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(@id)), @id)) as AfterPadding

set @id = replace('123.45', '.', '')
SELECT Convert(Varchar(8),CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(@id)), @id)) as AfterPadding
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c7047cf8759ff2598dbee2a5c029c1de) demo.

For your table, you need to apply like this.

```
Select 
     Convert(Varchar(8),
     CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 8 - LEN(Replace(Cast(AMOUNT as Varchar(10)), '.', ''))), 
     Replace(Cast(AMOUNT as Varchar(10)), '.', ''))
     ) as AmountInText
from SampleDataTable
```

Live [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06cb2ecb3dcd36e834fe1ce416c01528) demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for padding zeros , [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for removing the dot and [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for converting the value from string to number as next:-

```
SELECT LEFT('00000000'+ CONVERT(int,REPLACE('1234567.88', '.', '')),8) -- output: 12345678

SELECT Right('00000000'+ Convert(varchar(8), Convert(int,REPLACE('123.45', '.', ''))),8) -- output: 00012345
```

Comment: adbelqader I do not want all values to be replaced by zeros

Comment: I do not want to distrub existing values, above is replacing values for few cases

Comment: what are the other cases that you see my solution is not cover them ?

Comment: I have updated my question now, could you please help me

Comment: REPLACE(FORMAT(CAST(ROUND(((ISNULL(SchBenf.MBS_FEEAMT,0) * (ISNULL(SchBenf.GAP_Percentage,0)/100))),2) AS DECIMAL(10,2)),'000000.00'),'.','')   This is working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Input number: 1234567.88 in decimal/numeric format

```
SELECT RIGHT( '00000000' + LEFT( CAST( CAST( 1234567.88 * 100 AS DECIMAL( 15, 0 )) AS VARCHAR( 15 )), 8 ), 8 )
```

Output: 12345678

How it works:

1. `CAST( 1234567.88 * 100 AS DECIMAL( 15, 0 ))` - converting to a smaller
   precision automatically rounds the number (see [Converting decimal
   and numeric data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#converting-decimal-and-numeric-data))
2. `CAST( ... VARCHAR( 15 ))` - cast to string
3. `LEFT( ... , 8 )` - **truncate** number to 8 digits
4. `RIGHT( '00000000' + ... , 8 )` - add leading zeroes, then truncate
   keeping 8 rightmost characters

FYI: if you use decimal/numeric formats for your calculations then there is no need for "funny" number divisions and multiplications (`/.05)*.05`).

Comment: With `1234567.88` the statement returns `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.` error.

Comment: @Alex This seems working but returning only 7 digit value

Comment: @Alex here I need Decimal(10,2) where I need value of 2 digit after decimal. When I try to change above query it is returning 7 digits only

Comment: @ShwetaReddy, please update your question with your query where you are only getting 7 digits. In my tests I am still getting 8. See this: `DECLARE @a AS DECIMAL( 10, 2 ) = 1234567.88;
SELECT RIGHT( '00000000' + LEFT( CAST( CAST( @a * 100 AS DECIMAL( 15, 0 )) AS VARCHAR( 15 )), 8 ), 8 )`

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your reply. SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT('00000000'+LEFT(CAST(CAST( ROUND((((ISNULL(511.90,0)*(ISNULL(146.230,0)/100)))/.05)*.05,2) AS DECIMAL( 15,0)) AS VARCHAR( 15 )), 8 ), 8 ),'.','')  Can you please check this, I am not getting 2 decimal values in result.

Comment: @Alex edited my question , Can you please check select in question.

Comment: @ShwetaReddy as I said in my answer, you do not need any extra bits like * 0.05 / 0.05 etc. and also you do not need to replace anything in the string. The answer: `SELECT 
 RIGHT('00000000'+LEFT(
 CAST(CAST( ISNULL(511.90,0)*ISNULL(146.230,0) AS DECIMAL( 15,0)) AS VARCHAR( 15 )), 8 ), 8 )`. Are you sure the output should be 00074855 and not 07485513?

Comment: But to be fair, I suggest you try @Zhorov solution as it looks more elegant and seems to return same results.